# Only limited toolchain found in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt-creator

I'm working on a project that uses `MSVC2013` as compiler and I might have setup Qt incorrectly. The configuration of Qt Creator is really confusing.

From Option in Qt Creator [(click to view img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq4ul.png), it detected all the toolchains so I assume I can choose any of them and start working on it.

However, in project build configuration [(click to view img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKPZ0.png) it only allows me to choose one compiler.

I don't understand their relationship. What is the proper way to install Qt so that I can use it with MSVC2013 ?

PS: I installed Qt from an `qt-opensource-windows-x86-vs2010-4.8.7.exe` which should've supported up to MSVC2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded `qt-opensource-windows-x86-vs2010-4.8.7.exe`, it is only ever going to work with VS2010 (i.e. MSVC++ 9.0). Various Visual Studio versions are **not** compatible.

Note you are using Qt 4.8, which is old, and was only ever released with older compiler versions. If you really want to use this combination, you'll need to build Qt yourself.

The alternative (which I strongly suggest) is to just use Qt 5.6. It comes in a precompiled version for MSVS2013.

Comment: ty for your reply. I thought it would works for MSVC2013 because i found this folder `C:/Qt/4.8.7/mkspecs/win32-msvc2013` (Do you know what it is for ?). For some reason I only can use QT4 so i will probably build it myself.

Comment: That's because Qt's qmake comes with all *configurations* for the platforms it supports. Those are only for qmake, they say nothing about the Qt library binaries themselves. The makespecs are probably just there out of simplicity for the Qt developers: Selecting only a few or one would introduce additional complexity and unnecessary bugs.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually quiet easy.
You need to define a **Kit**. Sometimes a Kit is detected automatically.
A useful Kit needs at least a **Compiler** and a compatible Qt-Lib (**Qt Version**). The Qt-Versions are defined in the Tab next to Kits and (if not auto-detected) can be defined by setting the path to **qmake** of the version. The Compiler Tab is next to Qt Versions and shows the available compilers.